# Symfony class inheritance?

Tags: database, class, symfony, inheritance

Im not sure if I need to use class inheritance but I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish.
Let's say I have two classes:

```
class Car
{
    protected $id;
    protected $make;
    protected $model;
    protected $price;

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    /* more getters and setters */

}
```

and another class:

```
class Order
{
    protected $id;
    protected $carId;
    protected $quantity;
    protected $price;

    /* getters and setters */

}
```

In my controller I have $carId and $quantity and I need to calculate the price of that order. 
To look from database perspective single order can have only one car but single car can have many orders. I know I can accomplish this by making another query to the database to get the price but I think there should be a better way to do it. Maybe with class inheritance I don't know. so I would really appreciate if anyone could explain me some other way on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I think there is no way to use inheritance in this case (at least between these two entities). What are you actually trying to do? And where you are trying to define order's price (or car's)? On which action? On creating order?

Comment: as Micheal Sivolobov said it might be only relation by Car and Order. The price im trying to get is the price of the car so I could calculate the price of the order on creating order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand what you need. The case that you described is not about inheritance it is about relationship.

You need to add relation between `Car` and `Order`. If you use Doctrine as your ORM you can just follow instructions in the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Then you can call `$order->getCar()` to get `Car` entity that is related to your order.

Comment: Tried this but when i updated doctrine schema I saw that it includes all fields from car to order table and that isn't what I want. I don't need any extra fields in the database table.

Comment: You did something wrong. Relationship generates only foreign key in the "child" table. For example: you have relation `Order` N---1 `Car`. In your `order` table will be generated integer (same type as `Car`'s id) column `car_id` and foreign key constraint including `car_id` and `car.id`.